# $X$ is reflexive iff $X_R$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Problem:**

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space, $X_R$ its real version. Show that $X$ is reflexive if and only if $X_R$ is reflexive.

**My run at the solution:**

I suppose I should use the theorem, that space is reflexive iff
$$(\forall \varphi\in X^*) (\exists x\in X,\ ||x||=1):(\varphi(x)=||f||)$$

$\psi\in (X_R)^*$ is defined as $\psi(x)=\Re\{\varphi(x)\}$.

So my ideal is following:
$$||\psi||=\sup\{|\psi(x)|, ||x||=1\}$$
$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists x\in X_R,||x||=1):(||\psi||-\psi(x)<\varepsilon)$$
$$||\psi||=||\varphi||=\varphi(\tilde{x})$$
$$\varphi(\tilde{x})-\Re\{\varphi(x)\}=\Re\{\varphi(\tilde{x})-\varphi(x)\}<\varepsilon$$
Now I can define a sequence $(x_n)$ such that
$$\Re\{\varphi(\tilde{x})-\varphi(x_n)\}<\frac{1}{n}$$
I know that there exists $x^*\in X_R$, such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ (because it's a Banach space), so the following should be true:
$$\psi(x^*)=||\psi||$$
and that means $X_R$ is reflexive.

Is my solution correct? Am I missing something? Or is there a more straightforward solution?